# ¿Cómo poner un FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

Bueno veréis tengo este layout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**activity_pedido.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_default_descripcion"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sombra" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="05"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_light_button_pressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemmonth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="JUL"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_light_button_pressed"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>





    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="mi nombre"
            android:textSize="12pt"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_orange_dark"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemiduser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="53800"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemref"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="la referencia"
            android:textSize="12pt"
            ></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemaddr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="calle la tonta de cospedal"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            ></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemnoiva"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="31,28 EUR"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemiva"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6,57 EUR"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemprice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="37,85 EUR"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_light_button_pressed"></TextView>


    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_default_descripcion"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sombra" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/detailLista">

    </ListView>


  </LinearLayout>
```

quiero poner el `FloatingActionButton` en la esquina inferior derecha de la pantalla como en el whatsApp el boton de nevo chat.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

En este caso además de agregar el `FloatingActionButton` tienes que usar como contenedor principal un [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

...
...


  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

De esta forma se agregaría el `FloatingActionButton`a tu layout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No olvides agregar la dependencia de la Desing library para usar este boton:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    ...
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con que pongas el código genérico del `floating action button` en el layout en el que lo quieras tener valdría (el atributo `layout_gravity="end|bottom"` ya lo coloca en la parte inferior derecha) .

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/tu imagen"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Fuente: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button

Comment: gracias man !!!

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la nueva librería (AndroidX):

En dependencias debes añandir

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

y en el layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

lo que se veria como
[image: Floating Action Button]